# Can't Convert undefined or null?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const randomPuppy = require('random-puppy');
const subreddits = [
"memes",
"DeepFriedMemes",
"bonehurtingjuice",
"surrealmemes",
"dankmemes",
"meirl",
"me_irl",
"funny"
]

exports.exec = (client, message, args, user) => {
    var randSubreddit = subreddits[Math.round(Math.random() * (subreddits.length - 1))];

    randomPuppy(randSubreddit)
        .then(url => {
            const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setFooter(`${randSubreddit} ● Subreddit`)
                .setDescription(`[Image URL](${url})`)
                .setImage(url)
                .setColor(0);
            return message.channel.send({ embed });
        })

};
```

Hey guys, left discord coding behind about a year ago and I've come back to this error (title) It was working quite fine a year ago, and now nothing. (Haven't changed anything).
I'm a wee bit confused on how or why this is now happening.

Any help is appreciated as I've got no clue.

Thank you in advance :)

**Edit** - Not running Discord.js v12 so RichEmbed still applies. :)

```
[unhandledRejection]
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.entries (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\worrit\Downloads\Peepo_Redacted\Peepo_Revive\node_modules\lowercase-kevs\index.js:5:36)
    at normalizeArguments (C:\Users\worrit\Downloads\Peepo_Redacted\Peepo_Revive\node_modules\random-puppy\node_modules\got\index.js:222:5)
    at got (C:\Users\worrit\Downloads\Peepo_Redacted\Peepo_Revive\node_modules\random-puppy\node_modules\got\index.js:302:20)
    at randomPuppy (C:\Users\worrit\Downloads\Peepo_Redacted\Peepo_Revive\node_modules\random-puppy\index.js:31:12)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\worrit\Downloads\Peepo_Redacted\Peepo_Revive\node_modules\random-puppy\index.js:67:16)
    at Object.exports.exec (C:\Users\worrit\Downloads\Peepo_Redacted\Peepo_Revive\commands\image-fetch\meme.js:17:9)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\worrit\Downloads\Peepo_Redacted\Peepo_Revive\handlers\commandHandler.js:299:34)
[/unhandledRejection]
```

Comment: Do you know on which line the error occurred ?

Comment: Yea knowing the line number would be helpful, but I think it's either setImage or setColor, most likely setImage, log what url is and show the results.

Comment: edited original post to include error thrown. Completely overlooked that sorry. Maybe I shouldn't be using randompuppy anymore..

Comment: Like Karizma said, you should try to log the url, because it might be an object containing a little bit more than the url (I didn't use randomPuppy in a while, sorry if I am mistaking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const randomPuppy = require('random-puppy');
const subreddits = [
    "memes",
    "DeepFriedMemes",
    "bonehurtingjuice",
    "surrealmemes",
    "dankmemes",
    "meirl",
    "me_irl",
    "funny"
]

exports.exec = (client, message, args, user) => {
    var randSubreddit = subreddits[Math.round(Math.random() * (subreddits.length - 1))];
    randomPuppy(randSubreddit)
        .then(url => {
            const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setFooter(`${randSubreddit} ● Subreddit`)
                .setDescription(`[Image URL](${url})`)
                .setImage(url)
                .setColor(0);
            message.channel.send({embed});
        })

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is on this line. `embed` is undefined.

```
        return message.channel.send({ embed });
```

If this was working in the past and only recently stopped working then I suspect it's either one of two things;
One of the subreddits in your array no longer exists, or the api is outdated.

You can debug this by adding a `console.log(embed)` before the return statement and then one by one, remove each .function() call until embed no longer === undefined.

Might also be worth `npm install` every package again.

Comment: embed is defined though, by `const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()`

Comment: No it's not. Embed is the result of the chained functions after as well.

Comment: URL is the result of the promise. Embed is created after url is found yes, but embed is inited before `message.channel.send({ embed })`

Comment: Embed is the result of .setColor(0). which is returning undefined.

Comment: Yep it's the result of setColor, which if you look at the source code it resolves the argument and then returns this, which is the Embed. That's how the methods are able to chain, I've tried setColor(0) in v11.6.4 and v12 and they both work